# How can I prevent users from viewing the root directory of my laravel app?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I have a laravel 5 website with the following setup:

`http://localhost/my_app/public/auth/login`  - Users can view site using links like this

but if a user types something such as:

`http://localhost/my_app/`, he would be able to view the following:

```
Index of /my_app

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
[   ]   _ide_helper.php 2015-09-23 08:35    389K     
[DIR]   app/    2016-02-07 22:33    -    
[   ]   artisan 2015-08-30 12:31    1.6K     
[DIR]   bootstrap/  2015-08-30 12:31    -    
[   ]   composer.json   2016-01-03 04:51    1.4K     
[   ]   composer.lock   2016-01-03 04:52    130K     
[DIR]   config/ 2016-02-04 08:28    -    
[DIR]   database/   2015-08-30 12:31    -    
[   ]   gulpfile.js 2015-08-30 12:31    503  
[   ]   package.json    2015-08-30 12:31    159  
[   ]   phpspec.yml 2015-08-30 12:31    87   
[TXT]   phpunit.xml 2015-08-30 12:31    899  
[DIR]   public/ 2015-08-30 12:31    -    
[   ]   readme.md   2015-08-30 12:31    1.9K     
[DIR]   resources/  2015-08-30 12:31    -    
[   ]   server.php  2015-08-30 12:31    567  
[DIR]   storage/    2015-08-30 12:31    -    
[DIR]   tests/  2015-08-30 12:31    -    
[DIR]   vendor/ 2016-01-03 04:53
```

How can I block access to this directtory?

Answer (score 1):

Set your path directly to the public folder.

For local developement, run the command

```
php artisan serve
```

from your command prompt. Now you'll be able to access your app from  http://localhost:8000

When you upload it to server , you can just edit

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

to point your directory to

```
/var/www/html/public
```

Comment: Thanks @James for your input. For local development I am using XAMPP setup and have my app in htdocs. In my production server, I am suing Centos and have not seen the path `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Comment: Can you post the full path to your laravel folder in your local development? Which starts with C:/...

Comment: Go to command prompt and type: cd C:/opt/lampp/htdocs/my_app    Then type php artisan serve. Now try to access your app from localhost:8000

Comment: I am doing my development on linux. I can access the site using  localhost:8000 as well.

Comment: My question in the first place was that if some one types http://localhost/my_app/ whether on local or production server, he is able to view files of my root directory. How do I prevent that.

Comment: In local you will be the only person accessing the app using that localhost:8000. Now, which service are u using for production server?

Comment: On production server, my files are in a directory like this /var/www/html/my_app

Comment: If you cant find the path I specified, set the root directory of your domain to the public folder of your laravel app from your server control panel.

Comment: So the root directory for your domain will point to /var/www/html/my_app/public

Comment: I am using Microsoft Azure. On it I have set up Centos. I have full access.

Comment: Just give a google search on how to change your domain root directory and you'll be all good to go live.

Comment: I have just one problem, I have different apps in `/var/www/html` such as `/var/www/html/my_app/` and `/var/www/html/the_game/`. So if I set the root, how would I deal with the other apps.

Comment: If u go to the folder /etc/apache2/sites-available what are you seeing?

Comment: That folder doesn't seem to exist in Centos. My production server is running on Centos

Comment: Can you access /etc/apache2/ ?

Comment: It doesn't exist either

Comment: How are you checking the folder? Did you SSH into your server?

Comment: Yes I SSH into my server. I have full access.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7

Comment: Thanks for the link @Jilson. I will check it out and see.

Comment: Hello @Jilson, I have followed the tutorial but now I keep getting 404 error. What can be the problem?